# Specifying the escape character inserted by mysqldump in sql files

Tags: escaping, mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like to be able to control and specify the **escape character** used by **mysqldump** for data exports.

Instead of a `\` I would like to use a double backslash `\\` or `''`

Apart from `--fields-escaped-by=char` which seems to be used for tab delimited exports, I was not able to find any relevant option.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem. There is an [open bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65941) on this in MySQL's bug tracker (which is amazing because it's such a basic thing). My quick fix was to pipe mysqldump through sed:

```
[your mysqldump command] | sed "s/\\\'/''/g" > dumpfile.sql
```